# Storing large datasets efficiently on google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I know that there are a lot of dataset related queries on medium and datascience that address the issue of storing data
some of them are :upload data on github;using google drive
However let's say that I want to experiment with a dataset of size 48GB,then what are my options.
As per my understanding github starts giving you remote end hang up message,google drive has storage cap of 40 Gb
Any ideas should I try something like Amazon SE3 bucket
does a colab pro account help?

Answer (score 1):

Disk space in Colab Pro is double the amount available in the free version.

Comment: Thanks I was able to resolve it by upgrading my Google drive storage